# for the function $\frac{3x^2+4}{2x-1}$ find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts

Tags: functions

With this function I am unsure how to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts.

I am aware that to find the $x$ intercepts I need to put $y = 0$ and vice versa.

I have attempted finding the $x$ intercepts but I'm not sure what to do.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Use LaTeX to write mathematics in this site. Your functions isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

$$y(x)=\frac{3x^2+4}{2x-1},\quad x=0\to y(0)=-4,\quad y(x)=0\to3x^2+4=0\to3x^2=-4.$$ But $x^2>0\to$ That never happens. Also, the function has a pole in $x=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ intercept is the root(s) of the equation, i.e., where the graph $f(x)$ cuts the $x$ axis. Likewise, the $y$ intercept is where the graph, $f(x)$, cuts the $y$ axis.

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2 + 4}{2x - 1}$$

To find the $y$ intercept you set $x = 0$ in $f(x)$ and that will tell you were the graph cuts the $y$ axis.

$$f(0) = \frac{3(0)^2 + 4}{2(0) - 1} = -\frac{4}{1} = - 4$$

Therefore the y-intercept is $-4$.

To find the $x$ intercept you set $y/f(x) = 0$ and solve.

$$0 = \frac{3x^2 + 4}{2x - 1} \implies 3x^2 + 4 = 0 \implies x^2 = -\frac{4}{3}$$

Which cannot happen as you cannot square root negative numbers, and therefore there exists no $x$ intercepts which means $f(x)$ does not cut the $x$ axis. 
Here's how the [graph](https://www.google.com.jm/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ZmCWUsnKFuTKsQSalYHoDg#q=graph%20of%28%283x%5E2%29%20%2b%204%29/%282x%20-%201%29) looks.